# terraform apply resources based on tags

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-azure, terragrunt

i use terraform and terragrunt to deploy some aws infrastructure. there is a main terraform file , which uses many tf  modules. i use this in conjuction with tf variable files for deploying terraform in multiple environments, for example TF_ENV=dev terragrunt plan deploys in dev, TF_ENV=prod terragrunt plan deploys in prod.

i want to construct a disaster recovery environment , so i will need to use some of the existing modules and define some new specific ones.

some modules will be deployed with different configurations ( available in my dr.tfvars file) , some modules will not be deployed and some modules will be deployed just in the DR environment.

how i can achieve this?

i don't want to use count on the existing modules ( count = var.deploy_dr ? 1 : 0 ) , because this will result in lots of state changes and config refactoring .

is there any way to plan just specific resources ? or maybe exclude just some targets ? for example resources with tag deploy_dr = false?

i tried to put a tag "deploy_dr" = false to the unneeded resources,than save the plan as json and then filter it with jq. but the problem is that it will not exclude all the child resources ( resources created by the module)

in terraform you can target just single targets ,you don't have too many filtering options

Comment: Kindly share the code, what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `terragrunt`, but if you want to use a single config for various environments (i.e. doing `terraform init -reconfigure` and use some sort of script like `bash` or `python`), then I think your easiest option would be to use count.

Otherwise, if you have config for each environment, you can wrap resources in modules and just use those that you need for your environment. You can also use `-target` to target which modules or resources to apply.